# loop column and cell within a range

Tags: excel, vba, compare, match

T   U   F   T   F   F   F   T   T   T

T   U   F   T   T   T   T   T   T   T

T   U   F   T   T   F   T   T   F   T

T   U   F   T   T   F   T   T   F   T

I'm a novice to VBA and plz help if you are willing to. Thanks in advance.

I would like to first check column A with row 1 to 4 's value are the same. IF it is, A5.value shall return "TRUE".Here I mean no matter 4 cells are "T","U" or "F", they all return true in row 5.
When the first procedure is finished, I hope this same code looping through column A to J and check.

Next, I would like to check the remaining (not TRUE one in row 5), if there are 3 values are the same ( no matter "T","F" or "U") and return  TRUE in row 5 again.

And last, I want to check the remaining (still not TRUE one), if row 2 and 3 in that column are the same, then return TRUE in row 5.

Perhaps this is really simple but I can't figure it out now. Please help and I appreciate your help. Thanks. :)

Comment: Why not use a formula for this?

Comment: `=OR(COUNTIF(A1:A4,A1)>2,COUNTIF(A1:A4,A2)>2,A2=A3)`

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as adding the follwoing formula.

`=COUNTIF(A1:A4,A1)=COUNT(A1:A4)`

Comment: This only addresses the first requirement (all 4 values the same)